# Making google script more compact (script for clearing content)

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

So i have two schedules that are identical in row and column and placement of cells. There are cells that will be always constant but there are others where the fields will change. So i have a custom menu script that will call one of the two identical sheets and clear out the predefined cells. On the script side, basically I just copy/pasted the same script twice and changed the activesheet name. However, I feel like its so redundant. Is there a way that I can have just one script and depending on the menu item i select it'll wipe the appropriate schedule?

This is the custom menu script

```
  function resetsheetbutton() {
  var ui = SpreadsheetApp.getUi();
  ui.createMenu('Advanced Menu')
     .addSubMenu(ui.createMenu('Reset Schedule')
          .addItem('Schedule 1', 'resetschedule1')
          .addSeparator()
          .addItem('Schedule 2', 'resetschedule2'))
        .addToUi();
 }
```

This is the script to wipe out Schedule 1

```
function resetschedule1(){
   var spreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
 SpreadsheetApp.setActiveSheet(spreadsheet.getSheetByName('Notification'));
   var sheet = spreadsheet.getActiveSheet();
   var spreadsheet1 = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
 SpreadsheetApp.setActiveSheet(spreadsheet1.getSheetByName('Schedule 1'));
   var sheet1 = spreadsheet1.getActiveSheet();
   var startRow = 2;
   var lastRow = 80;
   var range = sheet.getRange(2,11,lastRow-startRow+1,1 );
   var numRows = range.getNumRows();
   var reset = range.getValues();


 for (var i = 0; i < numRows; i++) {
 var row = reset[i];
 sheet1.getRange(row).clearContent();
 }
   sheet1.getRange('C3').setValue('Insert new Date here');
   sheet1.getRange('D3').setValue('Insert this week's task');
   sheet1.getRange('D29').setValue('Insert this week's task');
   sheet1.getRange('D55').setValue('Insert this week's task');
   sheet1.getRange('D81').setValue('Insert this week's task');
   sheet1.getRange('D107').setValue('Insert this week's task');
   sheet1.getRange('C6').setValue('=C5');
   sheet1.getRange('C25').setValue('=C5');
   sheet1.getRange('C32').setValue('=C31');
   sheet1.getRange('C51').setValue('=C31');  
   sheet1.getRange('C58').setValue('=C57');
   sheet1.getRange('C77').setValue('=C57');  
   sheet1.getRange('C84').setValue('=C83');
   sheet1.getRange('C103').setValue('=C83');  
   sheet1.getRange('C110').setValue('=C109');
   sheet1.getRange('C129').setValue('=C109'); 
 }
```

This is the same exact script for schedule 2 except it points to schedule 2.
I specifically name the sheet instead of letting it wipe out the activesheet, so that on the off chance, the person clearing the schedule doesn't accidentally clear the wrong schedule.

```
function resetschedule2(){
   var spreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
 SpreadsheetApp.setActiveSheet(spreadsheet.getSheetByName('Notification'));
   var sheet = spreadsheet.getActiveSheet();
   var spreadsheet1 = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
 SpreadsheetApp.setActiveSheet(spreadsheet1.getSheetByName('Schedule 2'));
   var sheet1 = spreadsheet1.getActiveSheet();
   var startRow = 2;
   var lastRow = 80;
   var range = sheet.getRange(2,11,lastRow-startRow+1,1 );
   var numRows = range.getNumRows();
   var reset = range.getValues();


 for (var i = 0; i < numRows; i++) {
 var row = reset[i];
 sheet1.getRange(row).clearContent();
 }
   sheet1.getRange('C3').setValue('Insert new Date here');
   sheet1.getRange('D3').setValue('Insert this week's task');
   sheet1.getRange('D29').setValue('Insert this week's task');
   sheet1.getRange('D55').setValue('Insert this week's task');
   sheet1.getRange('D81').setValue('Insert this week's task');
   sheet1.getRange('D107').setValue('Insert this week's task');
   sheet1.getRange('C6').setValue('=C5');
   sheet1.getRange('C25').setValue('=C5');
   sheet1.getRange('C32').setValue('=C31');
   sheet1.getRange('C51').setValue('=C31');  
   sheet1.getRange('C58').setValue('=C57');
   sheet1.getRange('C77').setValue('=C57');  
   sheet1.getRange('C84').setValue('=C83');
   sheet1.getRange('C103').setValue('=C83');  
   sheet1.getRange('C110').setValue('=C109');
   sheet1.getRange('C129').setValue('=C109'); 
 }
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Adding this to comments as well. would you anyone be able to comment on the speed of execution. Right now I have a column of cell names.(e.g. A2,D3:D5,E7, etc) roughly 80 rows. I am running them through the loop. It takes about 25-40 seconds to run. I then stumbled across running them through the array function to speed it up but that didn't do anything with the speed. Is there nothing I can do for it run through the sheet and clear those cells faster?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because the function in the menu can not include a parameter, you'll still, initially need two functions, but they will be very short:

```
function resetschedule1() {
  resetschedule("1");//Pass the string value "1" to the function
};

function resetschedule2() {
  resetschedule("2");//Pass the value "2"
};
```

You could create an object for setting the values that are the same in both sheets.  With a JavaScript object you can match a "key" to a "value".   In this case the "key" would be the cell address, and the value would be the value.

```
var objCellToValueSameForBoth = {
  "C3":"Insert new Date here",
  "D3":"Insert this week's task"
};

//Set the values that are the same in both sheets
for (var key in objCellToValueSameForBoth) {
  sheet.getRange(key).setValue(objCellToValueSameForBoth[key]);
};
```

There is more than one way you can have the code use different values.  You can pass a value to the function:

```
function resetschedule(argWhichSheet) {

  var objArgToSheetName = {"1":"Schedule 1","2":"Schedule 2"};
  var whichSheetToClear = objArgToSheetName[argWhichSheet];

  SpreadsheetApp.setActiveSheet(spreadsheet1.getSheetByName(whichSheetToClear));
};
```

Comment: That worked beautifully and I learned something new! Thank you!

Comment: btw, would you be able to comment on the speed of execution. Right now I have a column of cell names. 80 rows. I am running them through the loop. It takes about 25-40 seconds to run. I then stumbled across running them through the array function to speed it up but that didn't do anything with the speed. Is there nothing I can do for it run through the sheet and clear those cells faster?

Comment: pleasefo not make an unrelated 2nd question. make a new question.

Comment: Sorry. It was related to the same script so I didn't want to clutter up the front page.